# Simulate click event in Matplotlib that triggers a pick event

Tags: python, matplotlib, picking

I have a Matplotlib figure, with some lines.
I have a `remove` function that is called when a line is picked.
The function simply removes the artist from the axes when the pick event is fired.

I would like to be able to programmatically simulate a mouse click that would trigger the pick event, if the `(x, y)` position of the click is exactly on (or close enough to) a line vertex.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def remove(event):
    event.artist.remove()

N = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(N):
    line, = ax.plot(np.random.random(2), np.random.random(2), '-o', picker=5.0)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', remove)
```

[image: figure]

I could call the `remove` function directly, with some `(x, y)` coordinates, but this would require me to know in advance which artist it corresponds to, instead of just letting Matplotlib figure that out, just like it does when I click with my mouse.

Basically, a function like `simulate_pick(ax, x, y)` that would:

- do nothing if the `(x, y)` coords are not close enough to a line on the figure
- call `remove` if `(x, y)` is close enough to a line